# How to check if Jquery is saved and embedded properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-development-server

I'm new to coding and currently getting trained on web development using jQuery.

I tried to run jQuery on my local server. I've downloaded the latest version of jQuery "jQuery 3.3.1-min.js". I've promptly saved it but when I checked if it is properly installed, it seems jQuery wasn't embedded correctly.

I used the exact following script to check:

```
if (typeof jQuery == "undefined") {
   alert("Not Correct");
} else {
   alert("Correct");
}
```

I need to know how to correctly install the jQuery over js.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: It's `jQuery`,  not `Jquery`

Comment: You would probably benefit from reading the guides at http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic, as HerrSerker points out the problem is just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

This May help........

```js
if(typeof jQuery === 'undefined'){
  console.log('no jQuery');
}else{
 console.log('jQuery is embedded!');
}
```

Comment: This reads like a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer. You should explain what you changed and why it should solve the problem.

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it on the head of html with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="/folder contain the js file/jQuery file">
</script>
</head>
```

Or find jQuery CDN, with this you don't need to download jQuery, it's hosted on Google or Microsoft and you can use it. Here is the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Google Hosted-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Microsoft Hosted-->
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: The question is about how to check if jQuery has loaded successfully (and the problem, as pointed out by HerrSerker, is just a typo) not how to load it.

Comment: He ask  "I need to know how to install correctly the jQuery over JS."

Comment: He also said "I used the exact following script to check" and that script is clearly broken.

Comment: I misunderstood his question.